# Saving a labeled image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have used the function `bwlabel` to label an image as follows:

```
[L, num] = bwlabel(I, 8);
```

For the the image I'm working with, say I have got 20 labels. Thus, when you run `unique(L)`, you will get a number list up to 20.

The issue is that when I `imwrite(L)`, and the run `unique` on that new written image, I get the values of the pixels as their intensity in the original image I labeled, and not as a labeled image.

How can I `imwrite` that labeled image, while keeping it as a labeled image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an image as an indexed image (with a colormap)

```
imwrite( L, rand( 256, 3 ), 'myIndexedImage.png' ); % wrirte
```

To read

```
[L cmp] = imread( 'myIndexedImage.png' ); % and you can ignore the colormap
```

Alternatively, convert to `uint8` and save labels as gray scales (assuming you do not have more than 256 labels)

```
imwrite( uint8(L), 'myLabels.png' );
```

To read

```
L = imread( 'myLabels.png' );
```

Be careful NOT to use any compressive format (e.g., jpg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why did you use `rand( 256, 3 )`? What does it represent?

Comment: @Simplicity when writing an indexed image you need to provide the colormap as well as the indices. you can replace `rand(256,3)` by any `n`-by-3 matrix as long as the number of rows (`n`) is greater-equal to number of labels you have in `L`: `n >= max(L(:))`.