# Assigining the pixel location

Tags: matlab, location, pixel, assign

I have the following matrix:

```
a =

     1     4
     6     4
```

After that, I created a zero matrix `new` of the same size of `a`:

```
new =

     0     0
     0     0
```

I'm trying to do the following:

- assign the location `(2,1)` in `a` to the variable `p`
- for that location in `new`, I want to give it the value `1`

For that, I did the following:

```
p=a(2,1);
new(p)=1;
```

But, I got the following:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, a matrix A cannot be resized.
```

It seems that also `p=a(2,1);` assigns the value at that location and not the location itself.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "location" you can use the linear index of that pixel:

```
p = sub2ind( size(a), 2, 1 );
new(p) = 1;
```

Comment: I would give you a +1 Shai, but I sincerely hope that @Simplicity stops getting answers in the MATLAB tag. I know you have been annoyed at the same user earlier. Answering doesn't help. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677692/saving-a-labeled-image), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679066/i-have-labeled-regions-but-where-are-they-on-the-image). And you're not the only one: [thewaywewalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680251/returning-specific-regions), and you again, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682446/finding-pixel-locations). There are more...